# Using the lower triangular portion of a matrix to return a Symmetric Positive Definite Matrix?

Tags: matrix-factorization

I've recently posted [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/246292/speeding-a-function-that-given-a-matrix-returns-a-close-by-positive-definite-ma?noredirect=1#comment619961_246292).
To summarise, I'm dealing with supposedly Symmetric Positive Definite(SPD) matrices, but due to machine-precision they end up not being SPD.
In a comment, a user suggested to use the lower triangular portion of the matrix.

1. I would like to be sure in what way we can use that? What algorithm is he possibly alluding to? I thought of the Cholesky Decomposition...
2. With that method, or another which uses the lower triangular part of the matrix, will I be able to take any 'almost' SPD matrix, and return an SPD matrix?

Comment: Is the matrix still symmetric or does it lose its symmetry due to machine-precision? Also, what computations do you do to update the symmetric matrix? If the updates can be represented as a sequence of rank one updates, then you could do the updates directly to the Cholesky factor for your matrix and that might help ensure your matrix remains PD.

Comment: What the answerer suggests is to define a macro/function which can be roughly expressed as "func Afromlower(i,j) : if i>j then return A(j,i), otherwise return A(i,j)". Then you can just use that function handle in place of the matrix and the regular algorithms can be applied directly (out-of-place of course, with this approach you would have to redesign the algorithms to do in-place computations).

Comment: W.r.t. your original question, you only need to add $c$ to the nonpositive eigenvalues.